# PHP Curl -o Parameter (output)

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, webclient

i want to download a file with php. The file is generated by a curl call.
So how i download the content generated out of the 
**-o Parameter** in php (output).

This is my Curl String out of Firefox:
curl --header "Host: myurl.org" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0         (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:1.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/1.0" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" --header "DNT: 1" --header "Connection: keep-alive" --header "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" "http://myurl.org/blabla/api_basic/api_wrapper.php?func=reportlist&user=xxx&pwd=xxx" **-o "ImportantFile.txt"** -L

If i try to download it with the response 
This is my php:

```
$fp = fopen($ausgabedatei, "w+");
$ch = curl_init();

// Set query data here with the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyport);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, (1024*1024*512));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
$details = curl_getinfo($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This code only gives back the Response of the call.

"0  successfull"
-1

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: "This code only gives back the Response of the call". What exactly do you mean by "gives back"? Are you saying that that is the contents of the file after you run the script? You have a number of variables in use above that are not defined in what you provided. I assume they've been defined elsewhere (but within scope)? One obvious difference between your command-line attempt and your PHP attempt is that you are not sending any headers in the PHP attempt. The remote host may require certain headers before sending the file.

Comment: Hi Patrick - it seems, that the response is only 
    "0 successfull" -1
I will try to fix the headers

Comment: You somehow managed to not answer the question that I asked.  Where are you seeing that response?  The the file to which you are writing?  In the terminal or browser (whichever you're using to execute the script)? Are you dumping `$content` or `$details` and not showing that?

Comment: Sorry, of course i do a 
    print $content;

I put it out in the browser and it is written in the file, too